# Struggling with the order of operations. Am I overthinking this?

Tags: python, boolean

I've been given the following, and I'm asked to give the type of value and the expression it returns:

`>>> b = 10`

`>>> c = b > 9`

`>>> c`

I know that in the first part, we're defining `b` to be 10, but in the second sentence, I'm interpreting this as: Define `c` to be equal to `b>9`. Now `b>9` as a value, doesn't make sense, so `c` can't be equal to it, so I put that the answer was `error` and the type was `Nonetype`.

The correct answer is apparently `True`, but why? Why do we take the `c=b` part first, and then ask whether it's >9? Is there some sort of standard order in which you're supposed to apply these things?

PS: What do the three `>>>` symbols mean in programming? I'm doing an introductory CS course, so please forgive any misnomers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's order precedence is [well documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). `b > 9` returns a boolean value that must be evaluated before it can be assigned with `c =`.

And `>>>` is part of the interpreter REPL. It doesn't have a specific meaning to all programming languages.

You could run your code in any Python interpreter to see what the output values are. I'm not sure what you mean by getting a Nonetype error as nothing is evaluated to None in those lines

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused between:

- the assignment operator (`=`), which assigns the result of the expression on the right side of the operator to the variable on the left side of the operator and;
- the equality operator (`==`), which tests the expressions on the right and left of the operator for equality and returns a boolean (true/false) value.

The first expression assigns the value 10 to the variable `b`. The second expression assigns the expression `b > 9` (i.e. 10 > 9), which evaluates to true, to `c`. Therefore, I hope you can see how `c` ends up being true.

The other issue you might need clarification on is that the `=` operator is *right associative*, which means that the expression to the right of the operator will be evaluated first. i.e. in the second line, `b > 9` is evaluated first before assigning the result (true) to `c`.

In answer to the second part of your question. Your code wouldn't actually compile as it stands in a regular C# compiler. I'm not sure what the `>>>` are. Are you using an online editor or something?

Valid C# code would be:

```
int b = 10;
bool c = b > 9;
Console.WriteLine(c); //Outputs true
```

Comment: To clarify, `c` is assigned the *result* of *evaluating* the expression `b > 9`, not the expression itself. `=` is not really an operator, either; the fact that you can write `a = b = 2` is a special property of the assignment *statement*, not the result of `a` being assigned any particular result of the "expression" `b = 2`.